# Set up server with Python

Tags: python

I want to check a javascript project, that requires access to files with google chrome. I tried to add:

**--allow-file-access-from-files 
--disable-web-security**

to the browser but because of multiple instances of chrome I could not get result.

Now I am trying to set a server with Python, so I won't have to access files. I installed Python 3.3.2 and set the directory path to my project file location. The code is:

```
python -m http.server
```

But I am getting

> File "(stdin)", line 1
>
> python -m http.server
>
> ```
>           ^
> ```
>
> SyndaxError: invalid syntax

I know that my problem is not problem for mozilla but I need to get it working with Chrome.

Comment: It really says "SyndaxError"? I don't quite understand the question, or if it's a programming question to begin with. :|

Comment: There is something wrong with your python installation as the syntax is valid and works well.

Comment: @ unwind I copied the message.

Comment: As it turns out, it must be sth wrong with the installation.. Puciek is right. I re-installed it and now it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the following command in shell (or cmd.exe). This is not python code.

```
python -m http.server
```